# String Split on Line Break

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a textbox on a MS Access form that users are going to copy a column of numbers into from an excel spreadsheet.  I need to take this input and use it as parameters to build a query.  I have code that looks like this

```
Dim data as variant
Dim input as String
data = Split(input,vbLf)
```

I want to be able to build a list of the input from the users but I can't figure out how to split it on the line break.  I've tried "\n\r", "\n". "\r", vbCrLf, vbLf.  The input looks like "12345[][]23456" with the box characters between each number

Thanks

Comment: If your data comes from a different OS, vbLf might be appropriate. I forget which is which, but I think Unix uses a linefeed alone and maybe Mac uses a carriage return alone. Windows users carriage return followed by linefeed. If you ever need to use data from other OS's you'll have to look it up! :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got Split to work for me using vbCrLf.  I also wrote the result of Split to a String array.

Here's my code:

```
Dim data() As String
Dim yourInput As String
data = Split(yourInput, vbCrLf)
```

Comment: I tested this out as well with a variant and it worked fine using vbCrLf.

Answer (score 3):

vbCRLF worked for me, try: `Strings.Chr(13) & Strings.Chr(10) (which is vbCRLF)`

try to see what is the ASCII code of those 2 boxes:

```
    //ex for input = "12345[][]23456"
    Strings.Asc(Strings.Mid(input, 6, 1)) 
    Strings.Asc(Strings.Mid(input, 7, 1))
```

Comment: Strings.Chr(10) for vbLf and Strings.Chr(13) for vbCRLF