# Get all occurrences of a "complex" substring in Excel VBA

Tags: string, excel, vba

I have sql stored procedure code in a string variable in Excel VBA, I am trying to get list of all table names used in this stored procedure. So each table starts with a schema name Prop.Table1 , Prop.Table2. 
I am doing a instr and trying to get the occurrence of Prop but how do I get the full name like Prop.Table1 , I cannot just use a mid because the table name would not always be followed by a space (it can be a line feed or space)

Input:

```
create proc test 
as 
begin
select * from Prop.Table1
join Prop.Table2 p
on Prop.Table1.col1=p.col1
end
```

Output:

```
Prop.Table1
Prop.Table2
```

I don't mind getting duplicate table names in my output.

Comment: I dont mind getting duplicate table names in my output

Comment: Could you post what you already have to get the `Prop` part of each occurence, so others complement that?

Comment: what is the database?  edit question with the name of database vendor, you might find that a clever database expert could point to a database function that can list the tables upon which the stored proc is dependent.

Comment: Joseph, did you find any contribution useful? Please remember giving feedback.

Comment: No I didnt actually. There were other complications in my source code, like for example few table names were referred without schema names, so it was difficult to figure them out. I didn't had the liberty to use any database in build stored procs.

Answer (score 0):

You want to deal with all possible "environments" where your target string `Prop.TableX` may show up, and you provided three sample cases (followed by newline, space, and dot).
So you want to:

1. Split your text into words using multiple delimiters.
   This is probably the hardest part.
   There are many options around, each with its pitfall.
   Bullet-proof code for this is [provided by the great Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/splitondelimiters.aspx).
2. Find all occurrences `stri` of `Prop`.
   This has been asked many times. As per your OP, I asume you have this.
   Just in case, you could adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35244353/2707864).
   See below
3. Keep `stri` plus the following word `strj` of each `Prop`.
   This is easy.
4. Concatenate `stri` (=`Prop`), `"."` and `strj` (=`TableX`).
   This is easy.

You could invert the order of items 1 and 2, with minor variations. E.g., splitting each time the remainder of the source string to find the second part of the substring.

---

Code for ítem 2, assuming `s` contains your source string where to look for `Prop`.

```
Dim srch As String
srch = "Prop"

Dim start As Integer, pos As Integer
start = 1
Do
  pos = InStr(start, s, srch, vbTextCompare)
  If pos > 0 Then
    start = pos + 1  'alternatively: start = pos + Len(srch)
    Debug.Print pos
    Debug.Print Mid(s, pos, Len(srch))
  End If
Loop While pos > 0
```